# Get Block name for getPriceHtml()

Tags: magento-1.9, layout, price, xml

I want to get block name from where `price.phtml` called.Also I cant find block name from `catalog.xml`.I fount this function but I don't know block name for this.

```
<?php echo $this->getPriceHtml($_product); ?>
```

Comment: enable block name hint in template path hint not working for this ??

Comment: do you want block type or block name  ??

Comment: template path hint not working thats why i'm asking

Comment: do you want class name or block type ??

Comment: i need block name

Comment: it's display somthing like Mage_Bundle_Price i'm not sure

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use hints for check block for each template:
 http://insync.co.in/how-to-enable-template-path-and-block-name-hints-in-magento-commerce/

or You can use xdebug for check all of it

or You can use this: `Mage::app()->getRequest()->getModuleName()`
fir check module name, and search for block You need

You can also display instance of `this` in phtml

or use `$this->getNameInLayout();`

Answer (score 3):

Use this:

```
$blocks = Mage::app()->getLayout()->getAllBlocks();
```

This will give you an array with the block instances. To get only the names use this:

```
$blockNames = array_keys($blocks);
```

Answer (score 2):

go to price.phtml and add below code to top of file it will show you block name of that file

```
$this->getNameInLayout();
```